# mouse coordinates variable's scope

Tags: visual-c++, global-variables, mouse, static-members

I am asking for an advice on how should I declare mouse coordinates that resides inside a `namespace` and use it frequently by all `class`es belonging to that `namespace`.
 I use to declared its variables as static within a `struct` and while dealing it with other `class`es, puts me in some random error linking between them.
 I like its scope to be globally declared but don't know how it should be done in proper way.

some of my implementations are like these:

```
struct Mouse {

    static double X,Y,Z;

    static int state,button;

}
```

//use it like

```
class Foo {

    void func() {

        Mouse::X = ?;
        Mouse::Y = ?;

    }

}


class Mouse {

    double X,Y,Z;

    int state, button;

}
```

//

```
class Foo {

     static Mouse mouse;
    //or
    Mouse* mouse;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

For me the example of class and using  dynamic Memory allocation is the best